# How to fix "Failed to get UI hierarchy" issue while recording espresso test in android studio

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I am getting this dialog when I am trying to add an assertion.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest in the Test Recorder feature in Android Studio. A [similar issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212959) is reported at the Android Studio issues tracker site and the team will be investigating it shortly. Please stay tuned and track progress there directly.